# past simple and past continuous - that summer

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

> He was staying in Rome that summer.
>
> He stayed in Rome that summer.

Can I use the two sentences above interchangeably? Or do they have slightly different meanings?

Comment: Since the "default" version is Simple Past, native speakers would normally expect some *reason* for choosing to use Past Continuous. Since you've given no particular context to justify the more complex verb form, you should probably stick to [the KISS principle,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) otherwise native speakers might just assume you're using "Indian English" (which non-idiomatically uses continuous forms in many contexts where mainstream Anglophones never do).

Comment: (Mainstream English: *I like my job*. Indian English: *I am liking my job.*)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I saw the first example in The Grammaring Guide to English Grammar (https://www.grammaring.com/past-continuous-for-actions-happening-over-a-period-of-time-in-the-past). Could you teach me when the first example can be used?

Comment: @FumbleFingers This reminded me of one my questions! It's interesting how "ask A if he's staying tonight" is preferable over "ask A if he stays tonight", but when it comes to a past situation that's exactly opposite. I guess that's because of the sentence essence. Here it looks to be a mere fact-reporting sentence without any uncertainty. However, the other one carries with it the sense of uncertainty in my humble opinion. ( link to that question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/136323/ask-jim-if-hes-staying-tonight-or-ask-jim-if-he-stays-tonight )

Comment: @Cardinal: That's a completely different usage wherein the ***BE + continuous*** verb form signifies ***future*** [intended, planned] action, rather than ***present***. But neither that nor OP's (*past* context) example have anything to do with "uncertainty" except in rather contrived situations such as *I was going to holiday abroad this year, but I'm not sure I can afford it*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see, by "uncertainty" I meant things related to the future or plans.

Comment: Can you tell me some contexts in which the first sentence can be used?

Comment: jinnyk216: The best advice is probably that you should *never* think about using Past Continuous in such contexts *unless* you're specifically interested in the ***timespan*** of the activity as opposed to ***the fact of it having taken place***. Thus, *He was staying in Rome when met his future wife* (i.e. - look out for contexts involving words like ***when, while***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I am a learner myself and I understand your confusion. I agree that the past simple is reporting a fact, but the past continuous can be used to emphasize a temporary or new situation "he was staying in Rome that summer, the rest of the year he stayed in Milan." That could be one reason to use the past continuous. One thing I have learnt is that context is everything.

Comment: No, it's not really relevant that the reported act might be "temporary" or "new". What's relevant is that the ***duration*** should be contextually significant (because *something else happened / was happening at the same time,* for example.